# How to change visibility of model in method via setVisible() method wicket ajax

Tags: java, html, ajax, button, wicket

So I do have my

public class MyClass extends WebPage {

```
static   AjaxFallbackLink ddd = null;
  static AjaxFallbackLink dddd = null;
```

(...)
}

and in constructor I do have :

ddd =  new AjaxFallbackLink("previous") {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
           // 
        }
    };
   ddd.setOutputMarkupId(true);
   ddd.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
   ddd.setVisible(false);
        add(ddd);
```

now I want to create a method which will change the visibility of this item.
However, calling ddd.setVisible(true); in this method does not work.

any sollutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your link like this adn set the condition where in should be visible in the `onConfigure()` method:

```
  AjaxLink myLink = new AjaxLink("myLink") {
     @Override
     public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        //click stuff done here
     }

     @Override
     protected void onConfigure() {
        super.onConfigure(); 
        setVisible(hereTheVisibleCondition);
     }
  };
```

This way whenever the link get's rendered it will be made visible or not depending by the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Robert's answer is generally considered more correct, however I will provide an alternative.

You are close on your implementation, but to do the update you have to call `target.add(myLink);` to get the ajax refresh of `myLink` (In earlier versions of Wicket it is `target.addComponent()`).

To change the visiblity with a method, you will have to pass an `AjaxRequestTarget`.  Within the `onClick` methods for an `AjaxButton` or `AjaxLink` you can call the following method:

```
private void updateVisibility(AjaxRequestTarget target, AjaxLink myLink, Boolean isVisible) {
    myLink.setVisible(isVisible);
    target.add(myLink);
}
```

Hope that helps!